# adminhtml multiselect attribute selection problem

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magento-1, adminhtml, multiselect-attribute

in Magento 1.9 admin panel, I have created a custom multi select category attribute but it doesn't show selected options after saving. Below is the code that I have used to create the attribute at category level.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "brands",  array(
'group'     => 'General Information',
"type"     => "varchar",
"backend"  => "",
"frontend" => "",
"label"    => "brands",
"input"    => "multiselect",
"class"    => "",
"source"   => "",
"global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
"visible"  => true,
"required" => false,
"user_defined"  => false,
"default" => "",
"searchable" => false,
"filterable" => false,
"comparable" => false,
'option' => array ( 'value' => array('optionone' => array('First Option'), 'optiontwo' => array('Second Option'), 'optionthree' => array('Third Option'), ) ),

"visible_on_front"  => false,
"unique"     => false,
"note"       => ""

));

$installer->endSetup();
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong or what shall be done to show the selected values.